LWC Lightning-Button change background color disabled button

Hi all, I would like to style the 'disabled' lightning-button the same as the 'black' button, however when using the following code this is not showing correctly inside my LWC. Is there a different way I need to perform this?
.slds-button_brand[disabled],.slds-button_brand:disabled,.slds-button--brand[disabled],.slds-button--brand:disabled {
    background-color: #000000!important;
    border-color: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-80, var(--lwc-brandDisabled,rgb(201, 199, 197)));
    color: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-100, var(--lwc-colorTextButtonBrandDisabled,rgb(255, 255, 255)))
}


Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400917/how-to-change-disabled-button-text-and-background-color-using-styling-hooks

Hi Tushar, I saw that was from 10 months ago, hopefully this had changed already or someone has found a solution

You can find all the button styling hooks here. There is no styling hook for the disabled.
